# url for hosted PayPal layout C

Tags: paypal

I have created a PayPal hosted checkout page using layout C, which is the layout to use in an iframe. I simply can't determine the url to use in the iframe!

I realize the answer is probably right under my nose, but believe me, I have looked.

Comment: Could you provide us more context?

Answer (score 0):

https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929/ has the answer in Part V, and a full basic demo zip at the bottom.

I recommend reading through that page, but in short:

```
<iframe src='https://payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKEN=.......&SECURETOKENID=........&MODE=TEST' width='490' height='565'
border='0' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the link you provided does answer this for me.